# vi and Vim does not show "insert" or "replace" popup

Tags: insert-mode

When editing with vi or Vim "insert" or replace popup text does not appear when in insert or replace mode.

This problem occurs both with Windows 7 and Putty interface and with Mac and Iterm2 interface.  Also, the problem is strange since it does not appear for one Windows 7 PC I use.

Comment: What is the output of `:set showmode?` ?

Comment: No response from ':set showmode' while in vi or vim.  Also, I failed to mention the problem is strange since the problem does not arise on one Windows 7 PC I use.

Comment: The question mark is part of the command, `:set showmode?`, not just `:set showmode`.

Comment: Do you use a `.vimrc` on your machines? Perhaps you are one `nocompatible` option away ...

Answer (score 2):

The `showmode` option is automatically enabled when you run Vim in "nocompatible mode" and automatically disabled if you run Vim in "compatible mode".

"compatible mode" is the default, it means Vim tries its best to behave like the original Vi, which is extremely annoying and impractical, therefore it is recommended to run Vim in "nocompatible mode". This can be achieved…

- by using the `-N` flag:

  ```
  $ vim -N foo.txt
  ```
- or by executing that command in Vim:

  ```
  :set nocompatible
  ```
- or by having a custom `vimrc` (empty or not) at any one of these default locations:

  on unix-like systems

  ```
  $HOME/.vimrc
  $HOME/.vim/vimrc
  ```

  on windows

  ```
  %userprofile%\_vimrc
  %userprofile%\vimfiles\vimrc
  ```